# Whipping File Inputs Into Shape with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to wrap the file input inside of a button using bootstrap. But I got a problem that I can not access to the input file, it means I can not upload file when using Internet Explore, while it working fine with Chrome.Does anyone get an idea why this problem happened?
. [Here is the Jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/hzve6arb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to wrap the file input inside of a button

That creates invalid HTML. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element:

> “Content model: Phrasing content, but there must be **no interactive content descendant**.”

(Highlight by me.)

`input` *is* interactive content (unless it has `type=hidden`), so it is not allowed as a descendant of `button`.

When you create invalid HTML to begin with, you can not expect consistent results across browsers. So say goodbye to your “input-inside-button” approach.

---

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/ has advice on how to style file inputs.

Comment: so could you suggest for me a solution for this, i want to keep this button  but because in button i can't add file so I must use input file tag inside of it

Comment: It is _not allowed_ to place a file `input` inside a `button` – so what kind of “solution” are you asking for here?

Comment: but why still it works with Chrome, do you have idea why ?

Comment: Because Chrome has decided to tolerate your faulty HTML, and auto-correct the behavior. But again, you can not expect every browser to do that, or in the same way. The only way to get reliable results is to write code without such errors to begin with.